# Error handler when no cells found in VBA (error 1004)

Tags: excel, vba

I am almost done with my macro but I am struggling with error handler. What I want is Message "no data found" and Exit Sub but I am not sure where exactly to put the code in my macro:

```
Sub test()

Dim src As Worksheet
Dim tgt As Worksheet
Dim filterRange As Range
Dim copyRange As Range
Dim lastRow As Long

Set src = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Set tgt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)

src.AutoFilterMode = False

lastRow = src.Range("J" & src.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
On Error Resume Next
Set filterRange = src.Range("A1:Q" & lastRow)
On Error GoTo 0
Set copyRange = src.Range("A2:Q" & lastRow)

filterRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 199, 206), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
filterRange.AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:="yes"

With tgt
    copyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).copy
If copyRange Is Nothing Then
    src.AutoFilterMode = False
    MsgBox "No data found"
    Exit Sub
Else
    tgt.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial
    src.AutoFilterMode = False
    MsgBox "Data found and updated"
End If
End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```

In other words I want to get rid of Run time error '1004'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably the laziest way to do it:

```
Sub test()

    On Error GoTo test_Error

    Dim src As Worksheet
    Dim tgt As Worksheet
    Dim filterRange As Range
    Dim copyRange As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Set src = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Set tgt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)

    src.AutoFilterMode = False

    lastRow = src.Range("J" & src.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set filterRange = src.Range("A1:Q" & lastRow)
    Set copyRange = src.Range("A2:Q" & lastRow)

    filterRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 199, 206), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
    filterRange.AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:="yes"

    With tgt
        copyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        If copyRange Is Nothing Then
            src.AutoFilterMode = False
        Else
            tgt.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial
            src.AutoFilterMode = False
            MsgBox "Data found and updated"
        End If
    End With
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False


   On Error GoTo 0
   Exit Sub

test_Error:

    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
        MsgBox "No data found"
    Else
        MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure test of Sub Modul1"
    End If

End Sub
```

Simply adding an erorr handler at the bottom, checking for error number 1004 and adding the messagebox you need.